# In Ubuntu, MoBlock makes it take a while to actually start using internet

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, internet, firewall

When connecting to wireless internet in Ubuntu (tested with two different networks), I connect nearly instantly. However, to actually load a page, I need to wait a few minutes, at which point I can actually use a web browser or Pidgin. Until then, various applications try to connect until they time out.

I've discovered that, if instead of waiting a few minutes, I open Terminal and run `sudo /etc/init.d/blockcontrol stop`, everything suddenly is able to load. I can then start MoBlock again with no ill effects.

Why is this happening? What is it that would cause MoBlock to take a few minutes to start letting traffic in, but only when started on bootup?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like it is verifying that the connection is there, but not actually handshaking and getting an IP until the connection is required. If, when you say "nearly instantly", you mean the length of time of one or two heartbeats, then that's what's happening. What version of Ubuntu is it?

Comment: 9.10 - Karmic Koala.

Comment: This didn't always happen - it started a few weeks ago, but I don't remember making any changes then in particular. After logging in it only takes a few seconds to show "connected" in the corner, but then takes minutes until the connection is actually usable.

Comment: You are not, perchance, using `tor` are you? It can take a while to get throughput when first signing onto the onion routing network.

Comment: Nope. Not using tor.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good troubleshooting guides in the Ubuntu Help pages.

https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/internet/C/troubleshooting.html